# Using a HashMap for search capabilites

Tags: java, data-structures

I need to use a data structure that can provide a low search time, but don't have a need to store key, value pairs.

All I need is to check if an element exists in a collection or not.

I'm thinking of inserting all the values from an array into a hashmap (with the key and value being the same) and then perform search operations on this.

Any alternatives or is this reasonable?

Comment: Why not use a List - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html? You can use Arrays.asList(array) to convert array to a list.

Comment: "check if an element exists"--this sounds exactly like a `Set`.

Comment: @Learner Because search time for an element in a list is O(n) (compared to O(1) in a hashmap)

Comment: `HashSet` is a good choice. Same deal as `HashMap`, just without having to deal with values.

Comment: You could use HashSet - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html

Comment: @chrylis Of course! Thank you

Comment: @RahulSaha - Ok, I haven't researched much into search complexities, but good to know that a Hash does search with O(1) complexity.

Comment: @Learner No problem!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to maintain key-value pairs, consider using `java.util.HashSet`

I assume your main use case would be adding elements to it and then calling 'contains' which has O(1) complexity

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need a HashMap for this? There are a few ArrayList Examples for this.

`ArrayList`, `List`, `LinkedList`

You can define the object you want to store in the List by using the diamond operator

`LinkedList<String>` this list now stores String values.

or as the comments suggested you can use a HashSet

```
HashSet<String> hashSet = new HashSet<>();
hashSet.add("Item");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go with **HashSet**. `contains(Object o)` method can help you in doing desired operation. It returns `true` if element is present otherwise returns `false`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Bloom Filter. it is used to test whether an element is a member of a set. False positive matches are possible, but false negatives are not – in other words, a query returns either "possibly in set" or "definitely not in set". Elements can be added to the set, but not removed (though this can be addressed with a "counting" filter); the more elements that are added to the set, the larger the probability of false positives.

[Cool article on Bloom Filters.](https://blog.medium.com/what-are-bloom-filters-1ec2a50c68ff)

Comment: Interesting topic